# Extract pieces of complex string

Tags: linux, string, bash, split

How can I get some of the values out of this string?

> using function abs using problem type ps Path found with total cost of 8 in 0.0 seconds Search nodes expanded: 183  victorious! Score: 502 Average Score: 502.0 Scores: 502.0 Win Rate: 1/1 (1.00) Record: Win

I need the values for total cost (8) and nodes expanded (183) in this example. (Maybe in another execution I have 47.)

I tried `${str:119:1}`, but sometimes the value changes to 10 or 100 and I only get one digit. I need the complete value.

Comment: Assuming that you'll be doing this more than one time, you might want to think about getting cleaner output, that would simplify extracting data, or switching to an output that is designed to be parsed or queried, ie. json or xml. Or writing a preprocessor that deletes unneeded words i.e. victorious! 1/1 or 1.0. And convert 2word phrases to 1 word, i.e. AvgScore, WinRate, SearchNodes (or nodesExpanded). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

`grep` can help you

example

```
$ grep -oP '(nodes expanded:|total cost of) [0-9]+' inputFile
total cost of 8
nodes expanded: 183
```

OR

if you dont what the string then

```
$ grep -oP '(nodes expanded:|total cost of) \K[0-9]+' input
8
183
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can split strings into "words" and print them. Example:

```
$ awk '{ print $3 }' <<< 'using function abs using [...]'
abs
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract those numbers:

```
$ echo "$str" | awk -v RS="" '{print $14,$21}'
8 183
```

If you want to capture those values as conveniently-named shell variables:

```
$ cost=$(echo "$str" | awk -v RS="" '{print $14}')
$ expanded=$(echo "$str" | awk -v RS="" '{print $21}')
```

To show that the above worked:

```
$ echo cost=$cost expanded=$expanded
cost=8 expanded=183
```